# Does Firebase SDK Authentication support Java/Sprint boot development?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have a Google Admin account and manage users via that console. I am building an application and would like to manage user logins through that application via a User Authentication service. I am doing some research into Firebase Auth and I think I found exactly what I need, but it does not seem to readily state that it supports Java Development. Does anyone know if this is in fact the case?

[image]

I have not tried anything yet. I have simply been researching.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Firebase Client SDK for Java.

However, if your Java Application is based on a three tiers architecture with an Application server (I guess this is the case since you use Spring Boot) you can use the [Admin SDK for Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to interact with the Authentication service (and if necessary the other Firebase services) from this server.

Comment: Hey @JakeMaxwell, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?